# How to send Notifications to the User whose post received a Comment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, notifications

With my current code the user who made the comment gets a notification telling them that they made a comment.

It should be the person who posted the Valuation that got commented on who should get a notification notifying them that someone commented on it.

Standard notification stuff, but where did I go wrong?!

**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :create_notification
  has_many :notifications
  has_many :comment_likes   
  has_many :likers, through: :comment_likes, class_name: 'User', source: :liker
  belongs_to :habit
  belongs_to :quantified
  belongs_to :valuation
  belongs_to :goal
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user, presence: true

private

  def create_notification # This is definitely the issue I made a lot of attempts to fix it, but now it's even more confusing
    @valuation = Valuation.find_by(self.valuation_id)
    @comment = Comment.find_by(self.id)
    @user = User.find_by(@comment.user_id).id
      self.notifications.create(
        comment: self,
        valuation: self.valuation,
        user: self.user,
        read: false
      )
  end
end
```

**notification.rb**

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :comment
  belongs_to :valuation
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**notifications_controller.rb**

```
  def index
    @notifications = current_user.notifications
    @notifications.each do |notification|
      notification.update_attribute(:read, true) 
    end
  end
```

**notifications/index**

```
<%= link_to notification.user_id, user_path(Comment.find_by(notification.comment_id).user.id) %> commented on <%= link_to "your value", notification_valuation_path(notification, notification.valuation_id) %>
```

**valuation.rb**

```
class Valuation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :activities
  acts_as_taggable
  has_many :combine_tags
  has_many :notifications
  validates :name, presence: true
    has_many :notes, as: :notable
    scope :publish, ->{ where(:conceal => false) }
    has_many :notes
  has_many :valuation_likes 
  has_many :likers, through: :valuation_likes, class_name: 'User', source: :liker
  has_many :comment_likes
    has_many :comments

  scope :randomize, -> do
      order('RANDOM()').
      take(1)
    end

    scope :top_25, -> do
      order('RANDOM()').
      limit(25)
    end
end
```

Please let me know if you need further **[explanation or code](http://evanamccullough.com/2014/11/ruby-on-rails-simple-notifications-system-tutorial/)** to help you help me :-]

Link is a tutorial I used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   def create_notification
      self.notifications.create(
        comment: self,
        valuation:  self.valuation,
        user: self.valuation.user, 
        read: false
      )
   end
```

Notification Link:

```
   <%= link_to notification.comment.user_id, user_path(notification.comment.user_id) %> commented on <%= link_to "your value", notification_valuation_path(notification, notification.valuation_id) %>
```

Comment: Not "post". It's "valuation" that is being posted and commented on. I'll give your code a try switching out post for valuation. Sorry I wasn't clearer

Comment: Try now updated code. And please no need to add instance variables in model methods

Comment: Got this weird error: `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in CommentsController#create
User(#70217700252220) expected, got Fixnum(#70217632216520)`

Comment: Done as per requested :)

Comment: Just tried and that sends the notification to the other user whose valuation it is but with the wrong user_id :/

Comment: the user's whose valuation it is should receive a notification saying "user 2 has commented on your value"  but it says user 1 instead even though user 2 is the commenter and user 1 is the person whose valuation it is

Comment: Sending to right user , but with wrong user Id? Are you taking about email content..

Comment: Your email template need slight modification.. Show me that

Comment: No not email sorry. It's just notifications that are sent via create action

Comment: You did it Pardeep! Thank you so much. I had fun with you guys battling it out. This issue has been on the back of my mind nagging at me so thanks again for sticking it out with me and getting it done :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this:

```
def create_notification
    @valuation = Valuation.find_by(self.valuation_id)
    @comment = Comment.find_by(self.id)
    @user = User.find_by(@valuation.user_id).id
      self.notifications.create(
        comment: self,
        valuation: self.valuation,
        user:@valuation.user,
        read: false
      )
  end
```

For the notification index try:

```
<%= link_to Comment.find_by(notification.comment_id).user.id, user_path(Comment.find_by(notification.comment_id).user.id) %> commented on <%= link_to "your value", notification_valuation_path(notification, notification.valuation_id) %>
```

Comment: `self.user` will be the user who has created comment not post.

Comment: Thanks for your help! That attempt didn't work though :/

Comment: Yea I just tried `self.valuation.user` and that sent a notification over to the right person but with the wrong `user_id` now for the notification

Comment: which user_id are you passing with the notification. Can you post that code?

Comment: I playing around with user_id 1 & 2. So 1 is commenting on 2's valuation, and so ur code sent the notification to 2, but said the notification was from 2 even though it was from 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80425/discussion-between-aakash-aggarwal-and-anthonygalli-com).

Comment: I think @AakashAggarwal its done..after your edit..:)

Comment: Thank you so much @AakashAggarwal for your help :) Pardeep won this battle :) I couldn't have done it without either one of u knocking away tho!

Comment: Hahaha, not an issue. It was fun :)