# How to set a notification conditional based on polymorphic comments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, notifications, comments, polymorphic-associations

I have this in **comment.rb**:

```
   def create_notification
      self.notifications.create(
        comment: self,
        goal: self.goal,
        valuation:  self.valuation,
        user: # How to fix this line?
          if valuation
            self.valuation.user,
          else goal
            self.goal.user,
          end           
        read: false
      )
   end
```

How can we make it where when the comment is on a valuation the notification uses `user: self.valuation.user` and when the comment is on a goal it uses `user: self.goal.user`?

Here's previous question if you need more context: [How to send Notifications to the User whose post received a Comment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30810128/how-to-send-notifications-to-the-user-whose-post-received-a-comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write something like this:

```
def create_notification
  author = valuation ? valuation.user : goal.user
  notifications.create(
    comment:   self,
    goal:      goal,
    valuation: valuation,
    user:      author,          
    read:      false
  )
end
```