# Trying to create a link inside of a model for a string variable, rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method inside of my message model for creating a notification and when the notification is created I'm also creating the contents for a string variable content. 
This is what the method looks like.

```
 def create_notification

  if self.conversation.sender_id == self.user_id
    sender = User.find(self.conversation.sender_id)
    Notification.create(content: "New message from #{sender.fullname}", user_id: self.conversation.recipient_id)
  else
    sender = User.find(self.conversation.recipient_id)
    Notification.create(content: "New message from #{sender.fullname}", user_id: self.conversation.sender_id)
  end
end
```

I would like to make the content "New message from #{sender.fullname}" all a link to converstations_path.
I have tried the following.

```
        Notification.create(content: "<a href="/converstions">New message from #{sender.fullname}</a>", user_id: self.conversation.recipient_id)
```

also

```
        Notification.create(content: "<%= link_to 'New message from #{sender.fullname}', conversations_path %>", user_id: self.conversation.recipient_id)
```

The result is it will render everything inside of the quotation marks ignoring the html or the link_to helper. How can I make this a link?

I am rendering the notification.content inside of my _notification.html.erb this is what the file looks like

```
<strong><%= notification.content %></strong>
<span class="pull-right"><%= notification.created_at.to_formatted_s(:short) %></span>
```

Comment: where is the `notification.content` being used?

Comment: The notification.content is being used inside of  _notification.html.erb this is what the file looks like. I'll add it to my main post.

Comment: You can refer this previous [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30810128/how-to-send-notifications-to-the-user-whose-post-received-a-comment)

Comment: IMO, generating HTML in a model method seems like a bad idea. But, if it floats your boat, okay then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this is to add a field to your notification model, such as `src`. This `src` would be the link that you would like to send the user to. Then, whenever you are rendering this notification to the user, you can use the `notification.src` in your `link_to`, instead.

This would be my recommended approach, however I believe you could also use something like `notification.content.html_safe` in order to parse+render the HTML instead of just rendering it.

Comment: Thank you JGrishey, I added the .html_safe as you said and it works perfectly

Answer (score -1):

I tried to solve this issue by referring [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249431/put-a-link-in-a-flashnotice)

```
(Model)sender = User.find(self.conversation.sender_id)

link = "<a href ='URL'>New message from #{sender.fullname}</a>"

Notification.create(content: "#{link}", user_id: self.conversation.recipient_id)

(View)<%= notification.content.html_safe %>
```

Comment: please add  <a href></a> to New message〜